# Adding in app purchases with purchase automatically turned on for some users

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to revamp the purchase model on one of my iphone apps to use in app purchasing to unlock the full featured app instead of having two separate apps.  Is there a way to do this so that anyone who has previously purchases the app can get the purchase for free automatically?

Comment: Err I hate apple and that whole concept, by default they leave those in app purchases on...2 year old cost me a lot of money because of that!

Answer (score 1):

The strategy that I used is to create a **NSUserDefaults** for previous purchasers of the application. Then I put that version in the app store for a month. I picked a month so that hopefully that all users had a chance to up date the app. After a month I put the in app purchase feature into the app and put that in the app store.

When I test to if I should use any in app purchase content I also check to see if the **NSUserDetaults** I created in the previous version is set.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently any way for the user to be given the In-App Purchase item for free.

However, if you can detect that the user upgraded from the old version (e.g. by examining NSUserDefaults) you can easily enough have your "did they purchase the full version?" check return true for that case too.

Comment: This is the best option.  Of course if they ever change devices or delete and reinstall, you will lose that information.

Comment: Your only other option is to provide some other type of unlock code if someone ever loses out.  If the app is <$1.99 it's not really worth the effort.